# Does cropping a picture change or remove properties like geotag data?

Tags: geolocation

When you crop a picture to send via your smartphone for example (WhatsApp), what happens to its properties such as GeoTag data, date the phot was taken and so on?

I want to make sure I do not disclose such information to other people.

Comment: Metadata is separate from the image's contents. Get a metadata tag editor if you want to edit metadata.

Comment: This is something that is easy to test. I'm not sure this is an InfoSec question.

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on the application used for editing the picture.

The application can retain the metadata, remove it and/or replace it with own metadata.

When you want to make sure that no incriminating metadata remains in an image, edit it with an image editor which allows you to view and edit all metadata fields of the image. For recommendations, check out https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

But be aware that when you sanitize an image before sending it, the sending application might add additional metadata. With an application like WhatsApp, which is closed source, frequently updated, stores unencrypted messages on its own server and is owned by a company with a post-privacy mentality, it is hard to tell if, under what conditions and what kind of metadata it might add to your messages. Possible information an application like WhatsApp has available and *could* embed in a sent image are for example:

- Application-specific username
- Unique identifier of sending device
- GPS location when sending the image
- Time when the image file was created and last changed on the device filesystem
- Time when the image was sent and received